# SPD crashes when checking for errors

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have just made one workflow so far, my very first. When I click the button **Check for Errors**, SPD crashes then restarts. Is it possible that there is something wrong with my workflow? Or should I reinstall my SPD? This is really irritating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run the diagnostics to make sure everything is ok, could be wrong or conflict version, could be just 2013 spd as its tempramental at the moment, also want to know what version of spd are you using (preview or full)and what arc is it (32 or 64) and finally have you updated to latest version?.

either way run this tool just to make sure all is ok!

SharePoint Designer

1.On the Help menu, click Office Diagnostics.

2.Click Continue, and then click Start Diagnostics.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-designer-help/diagnose-and-repair-crashing-office-programs-by-using-office-diagnostics-HA001234076.aspx#BM28

lastly if its still a pain and cant solve it than your best bet would probably would need to re-install spd but you could run into the same issue! have you checked eventviewer for any errors that it generates:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997769(v=exchg.65).aspx

Comment: I am using SPD 2013, 64-bit. All updates are installed.

Comment: I reinstalled my SPD 2013 and it's working fine now. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Can we see how exactly did you configure the workflow? Is it SPD 2010 or 2013?

SharePoint Designer is not really a top notch tool, and I find that it crashes more often than not in my environment. I just tend to mumble a few swear words and restart the tool, until it crashes on me again.

Also reinstalling might be an option to look into.

Comment: It is SPD 2013. My SPD was not crashing this past few days. Only today when I remade my workflow. It's just a simple sequential workflow with approval. Maybe I really should reinstall it!

Comment: Please try, and check if you have proper permissions to create such workflow. Maybe see the event logs as well?

Comment: I am very sure that I have proper permissions. It occurred to me again. I reinstalled it and it's okay again! Sigh.